# Multiple Column Constraint

Tags: sql-server-2005, check-constraints

I have a table with three columns, the ID of the relation, the ID of the object related and the value of the object. The table may have as many repeated ID-Value relations except when the Value is 0 for the same ID.

> ```
>               Correct                       Incorrect
>     +--------+--------+-------+    +--------+--------+-------+
>     | PK_ID  |   ID   | Value |    | PK_ID  |   ID   | Value |
>     +--------+--------+-------+    +--------+--------+-------+
>     |   1    |   1    |   1   |    |   1    |   1    |   1   |
>     |   2    |   1    |   1   |    |   2    |   1    |   1   |
>     |   3    |   2    |   0   |    |   3    |   2    |   0   |
>     +--------+--------+-------+    |   4    |   2    |   0   |
>                                    +--------+--------+-------+
> ```

The question is how can I enforce it not to allow a repeated ID-Value relation when the value is 0?

Comment: Can't do this with a check constraint. Use a filtered index or a view with a unique constraint dependant on version of SQL Server.

Comment: @Martin yes that's exactly what I need, but I'm on SQL Server 05

Comment: You need to use the indexed view technique then. There is an example in my answer in the "possible duplicate" link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by `@Martin Smith` in the comments of the question this is indeed similar to [Simple CHECK Constraint not so simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210680/simple-check-constraint-not-so-simple) and in the answer to that question (although it was for sql-08) there's an example solution for sql-00 and 05.

The idea is to create an index view to simulate a filtered unique index with the following code:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.myTableView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT ID
FROM dbo.myTable
WHERE Value = 0

GO 
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED  INDEX ix ON dbo.myTableView(ID)
```