# Can i create a unique constraint on 2 fields and a condition on a boolean field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple CHECK Constraint not so simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210680/simple-check-constraint-not-so-simple)

we have a table with roles for a user.
It looks like this:

```
Id, RoleId, PersonId, Active
```

The active column is used for softdelete functionallity: when you delete a role for a user, you actually set `active` to `false`.
So you can have multiple rows with the same `roleid-personid-active` combination, but only when the active bit is set to false.
So this is valid data:

```
Id   RoleId   PersonId   Active
1    1        1          false
2    1        1          false
3    1        1          false
4    1        1          false
```

but this isn't, because you can have only one active role on any moment (so record 3 should not be inserted):

```
Id  RoleId  PersonId  Active
1   1       1         false
2   1       1         true
3   1       1         true
```

My question is: can i create a unique constraint on `RoleId, PersonId and Active`, where `active` equals to `true`?

ps. Sql server version is 2005

Answer (score 2):

You can use a unique constraint on `RoleId`, `PersonId` and a computed column that holds `Id` for all inactive roles and `null` for all active roles.

```
create table Roles
(
  Id int identity primary key,
  RoleId int not null,
  PersonId int not null,
  Active bit,
  ActiveInt as case Active when 0 then Id end,
  constraint UQ_RolePersonActive unique (RoleId, PersonId, ActiveInt)
)
```